# Which HTTP status codes do we get when our request to Bot Framework REST API has been timed out?

Tags: rest, botframework

We are developing a bot system using Bot Framework REST API and have 2 questions about request timeouts of APIs.

1. Which HTTP status codes do we get when our request to Bot Framework REST API has been timed out?

I referred to the HTTP status codes on this page. But I couldn't find the answer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference

2. After how long time will our requests to Bot Framework REST APIs be timed out? (e.g. 60s)

Thank you for your cooperation!

Comment: There is a 15 sec timeout on the Bot Connector REST API.

Comment: Thank you  very much for the information!

Do you know which HTTP status codes we get when our request to Bot Framework REST API has been timed out?

Comment: 502 means your bot is down or not responding, 503 means the REST API service is down or not responding.

Comment: Thank you very much! Then is it correct to understand that we get HTTP status code 502 or 503 when our request has been timed out?